# How to determine which URL scheme to use in `application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL`

Tags: ios, swift, url-scheme

I integrated Google Drive SDK into my app. Now I want to integrate Dropbox too, in the feature maybe more other cloud drive. As now there are two URL schemes, how could I determine which URL scheme is using in AppDelegate method `func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url:` when the signin occurs?

Because I have given each URL scheme an identifier in info.plist. I think maybe I could use `url.scheme.identifer` to distinguish each other, but the attemp is failed. They don't have that chain property.

Or maybe I could set a flag manually when a user press the signin button. So what is proper way do it?

```
    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        
        // Google SignIn
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.handle(url)
        
        // Dropbox SignIn
        return DropboxClientsManager.handleRedirectURL(url) { authResult in
            guard let authResult = authResult else { return }
            switch authResult {
            case .success(let token):
                print("Success! User is logged into Dropbox with token: \(token)")
            case .cancel:
                print("User canceld OAuth flow.")
            case .error(let error, let description):
                print("Error \(error): \(String(describing: description))")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check out #2 in the google documentation: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in where it says "// Handle other custom URL types.". I think that's basically where you'd return dropbox's handle

Comment: Thanks, that is a correct way to determine if it is from google signin or not. But I still need a way to check which the URL scheme is from because there would be more cloud drives like One Drive, Mega in the plan.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.handle(url) == true {
      return true
} else {
      return DropboxClientsManager.handleRedirectURL(url) { authResult in
             guard let authResult = authResult else { return }
             switch authResult {
             case .success(let token):
                 print("Success! User is logged into Dropbox with token: \(token)")
             case .cancel:
                 print("User canceld OAuth flow.")
             case .error(let error, let description):
                 print("Error \(error): \(String(describing: description))")
             }
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after a few of test. Now I have added a flag in my dependency, then each time a user press a SignIn button, the flag will be set accordingly like `google drive` or `dropbox`.

When `open url` method in AppDelegate or SceneDelegate is triggered. It will check this flag first to open url scheme. For now it is working well, though I'm not sure if it is the best practice.

```
    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        guard let urlFlag = MyDependency.urlFlag else { return false }
        
        if urlFlag == .googleDrive {
            // Google SignIn
            return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.handle(url)
        } else if {
            ///
        } else if {
            ///
        }
        
        return false
    }
```